# Record Set Issue in Ms Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm new to ms access VBA, I have a form and table  in ms access 2007.
in my table I will import some values for processing through this form.
in that form I'm having 5 textboxes I want to text box should fill the values automatically. using the rs
Here I need to create one recordset to make it easy for the user's
I have created one Query for this. but I'm facing some error messages when my page loads.

```
Private sub Form_Load() 
Dim strqry as string  
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset  
strQry="select xyz,abc,ffg from tblImport where isworked='N'"  
set rs = currentdb.openrecordset(strqry)

if not (rs.EOF and rs.BOF) then  
me.textbox0.value=Cstr(rs!xyz)  
me.textbox1.value=Cstr(rs!abc)  
end if

End sub
```

Here I 'm facing two error messages while form loads
1. type Mismatch runtime error 13
2. object variable or with variable not set , runtime error 91
can any one help me on this ?
Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DAO:

```
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset
```

That requires a reference for **Microsoft Office xx.0 Access database engine Object Library** to be set.

Comment: Yes, Its working fine, all the issues and error messages gone ! thanks guys.

Comment: Now I have one more doubt. I need to update that field itself for this I'm using the query as follows.  str=" Update tblImport set isworked='Y' where claimId=' " & cstr(rs!CalimId)  but it's not updating that field I checked with debug print then it's showing as update tblimport set isworked='Y' where claimId='121212121     This much last  ' is not coming could you please help me to fix this?

Comment: Try removing the space and typo: `" … where ClaimId='" & CStr(rs!ClaimId.Value) & "'"`.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and replies it's working fine, thank you all